# Basic Media Queries Not Working

Tags: css

Not quite sure why my media queries aren't working. Very much a beginner. Trying to get the navigation menu to respond similarly to

http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav

Normal media queries don't work either, I know i don't have topnav as the class setting for the nav like they do in the w3 example. I just have been using nav.

```
/**********************************
GENERAL
***********************************/
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
background: rgba(226,226,226,1);
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
}

li{
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline
}

#wrapper{
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  /*min-height: calc(100vh - 120px);*/
    /* 80px header + 40px footer = 120px  */
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: visible;
  position:relative;
  background: rgba(147,206,222,1);


}

img{
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding:1px;
  border:1px solid #021a40;
}

h1{
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  font-family: Garamond;
}

/**********************************
HEADING
***********************************/
header{
  color:blue;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  padding: 20px 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 32;
}


/**********************************
NAVIGATION
***********************************/
nav{
  max-width: 100%;
  max height: 100%;
  padding: 3.5em;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: Garamond;


}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 10px 20px; /*pushes div down*/
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  /*background-color: purple;*/
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;

}

nav menu:{



}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav a, a:link, a:visited {
  font-weight: 800;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  /*border-style: double;*/
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;

}

a:hover{
  background-color: gray;
}

#back-to-hp{
  text-align: left;
}

/**********************************
FOOTER
***********************************/
footer {
background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  /*max-height: 100%;
    position:relative;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align: center;*/
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-top: 15px;

}
}



/**********************************
PAGE: ADOPTION
***********************************/
#image-paragraph{
  font-size: 20;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
}
#content{
font-family: Garamond;

}
/**********************************
PAGE: ABOUT
***********************************/



/**********************************
PAGE: CONTACT
***********************************/


/**********************************
COLORS
***********************************/

/**********************************
MEDIA QUERIES
***********************************/
/*@media all (max-width: 960px) {
  body{
    background-color: royalblue;
  }
p{
  color:white;
}
}

@@media (min-width:481px) and (max-width: 700px) {


}*/

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.nav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  ul.nav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.nav.responsive {position: relative;}
  ul.nav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.nav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.nav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

Comment: They're working fine, please make sure your [browser supports css media query](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries) and has its viewport width less or equal than `680px`.

Comment: I've been using chrome, but nothing is still showing. Using the inspect tool to check, perhaps its something wrong with my html?

Comment: Can you make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) out of it?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dt71w9uo/

Comment: Why are you putting your html elements inside of `<head>` tag? Please move them into the `<body>` tag..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two media queries set at the max-width of 680px. Possibly one was meant to be a min-width? If not then I don't see why you didn't put all of it under a single media query.

**EDIT:**
Try changing `ul.nav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}` to `nav ul li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}`.
This is because media queries read css as nested from their parents, so you need to include the parent elements correctly.
Also, from experience, I've noticed `visibility: hidden;` consistently works better in many scenarios than `display: none;`. This depends on your element positioning, though. Either works in your case.

Comment: As said by choz, a fiddle would be heplful.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. Hopefully my edit helps you out.